# integral of Bessel function of first kind with Hyperbolic function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions, hyperbolic-functions

I'd like to solve the following equations:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{J_{0}(z)+J_{2}(z)}{z+a_{0}+a_{1}\left(\operatorname{coth}\left(a_{2}z\right)-1\right)} dz$$
where $J_{0}$ and $J_{2}$ are Bessel functions of first kind. $a_{0},\,a_{1},\,a_{2}$ are real positive constant.

I find some interesting identity shown as:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\nu} J_{\nu}(a x)}{x+k} d x=\frac{\pi k^{\nu}}{2 \cos \nu \pi}\left[\mathbf{H}_{-\nu}(a k)-Y_{-\nu}(a k)\right] \quad\left[-\frac{1}{2}<\operatorname{Re} \nu<\frac{3}{2}, \quad a>0, \quad|\arg k|<\pi\right]
$$
where $\mathbf{H}_{-\nu}$ is Struve function and $Y_{-\nu}$ is Bessel function of second kind.
But I do not know how to use this.

Any ideas on how to tackle the first integral? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What makes you think that this will have a nice solution? And why are you interested in it/where did it come from?

Comment: I encounter this when I trying to find the green function of the Stokes equation on a planar surface. I suppose it should be some combination of Struve function and Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: About the used terms: it is not an "equation to be solved", it is an integral that you would like to obtain under an "explicit form"; moreover, when you say you obtain this integral, could you say with which software (Mathematica ?). It is important not to omit information.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. the identity I found on a textbook: Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, 7th edition.